# Sum of all corresponding values of a particular calendar month and sum of all corresponding values up to its previous month?

Tags: excel-formula

An Excel sheet contains an array of calendar months which appears more than once and these months have numerical value in the corresponding cell. 
(1) How to find the sum of all values of any random month and 
(2) How to find the sum of all values up to it's previous month?
However, I solved Question (1), but I am unable to solve Question (2), please help. I have attached the Excel file for ready reference. Thank you for your help in advance https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3usfgftcvy50ly/Bill.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: As a new user, be sure to familiarize yourself with the way the website works. If your question has been answered below, select the answer that solved it as the correct answer so the poster can get credit. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found creating a dynamic named range to a handy tool.

In Name Manager (On the formulas tab), select "New..." I used the name "DynamicBill", for the formula I used:

`=OFFSET(DATA!$C$7,0,0,MATCH(CALCULATION!$B$1,UNIVERSE[Month],0)-1,1)`

In `CALCULATION!$C$4` I used the formula: `=SUM(DynamicBill)`

[image]

A [LINK](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak6r9nlUd1ZOjPA4KMnQ4sHmgeCk_A) to the demo file working with my tweak.

Comment: Please note, this doesn't filter through and remove values that are for other companies. But you could do another dynamic range for the companies up to the specified month (Just change the formula I used from `Data!$C$7` to `Data!$B$7`, and give it a name like "DynamicCompany". Once you have a dynamic company range you can SUMIFS for that dynamic range.

Comment: Hello Jeranon, thank you very much for the solution. It works!

Comment: If it works for you, please select or add the right answer (by the up and down arrows on the left) - it increases my ability to do more on this site. Thank you :)

Comment: Hello Jeranon, thank you very much for the solution. It works great! However if there are more than one company, how to execute the same for individual companies? I have uploaded the file for your reference please https://www.dropbox.com/s/ti1w0ti0ygmk0nx/Bill_New.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I mentioned how in the first comment above: Create a named range that will resize dynamically (like the DynamicBill named range). To do this, simply copy the DynamicBill formula, change the `Data!$C$7` to `Data!$B$7` and give it a name like "DynamicCompany". Once you have that, you can use `SUMIFS` to reference the Company column and match that against the company name you enter and then it only adds the numbers "in line" with the company you specify. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the month into a date which can be evaluated. This formula sums up all the values for the month in B1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(DATEVALUE("01"&A2:A55&"2018"))=MONTH(DATEVALUE("01"&$B$1&"2018")))*(C2:C55))
```

This formula sums the values up till the previous month of B1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(DATEVALUE("01"&A2:A55&"2018"))<MONTH(DATEVALUE("01"&$B$1&"2018")))*(C2:C55))
```

**ARRAY FORMULAS: press  CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**